# How to add apps to the new-style right-click menu in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, context-menu

How can I add apps to the **new-style** right-click menu in Windows 11? What is the exact registry key?

Adding keys to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xxx\shell` only adds apps on the legacy right-click menu, but what I am talking about is to add apps on the **new-style** right-click menu.

[image: How to add apps to the new-style right-click menu in Windows 11]

Comment: I didn't manage to do that but you can revert to the old-style menu which I did soon after experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: Try with [Custom Context Menu](https://github.com/ikas-mc/ContextMenuForWindows11).